# Possible to Combine Boolean Attributes into a Select Menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu, boolean

I have 3 boolean fields in my application that define an event status.

An event can either be guaranteed, bonus or pending, which are all boolean fields. The event, as stated above, can only be one of the listed.

I have it set up now as checkbox/radio buttons so when one is chosen, it reverts the other options to "false".

I am wanting to add these options to a drop down select instead if possible to make it flow nicer with the application.

Is it possible to achieve this where all these items: guaranteed, bonus, pending are added to a single drop down and then when one is chosen, it passes that as "true" and makes sure the others are false?

Comment: I wonder why you use three different fields for this. You should have used one field 'integer' and use 0,1,2 for your respected event status

Comment: Each one of these boolean fields activates a color on an event calendar. In example, if the event is "Pending" it will display the event on the calendar with a 'red' background. That is the main purpose behind using each as a boolean. I have an "if-else" statement running which corresponds to a css class that will be displayed on the calendar.

Comment: Two events can simultaneously happen? If no which seems the case then you only need 1variable/column in your table, and save 0,1,2 respectively

Comment: The thing you are looking is quite possible but for this you have to write extra logic in your controller